# Using a pre-loader image to hide tinymce source code till the content loads

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce, preloader

We have integrated Tinymce for the system i am developing. My boss wants me to use a loading image till the full content loads within Tinymce textarea. I need just to hide HTML under a preloader til the content loads. Do anyone of you have an idea how i can do this?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: `style="display:none"` if you use javascript: `document.getElementById('id').style.display = "none";`

Comment: no i want to use a preloader... no just to hide it , i edited the question.

Comment: You can have to functions: `displayPreloader() { document.getElementById('preloaderId').style.display = "block";document.getElementById('tinymceContainerId').style.display = "none"; }` and second one on tinymce load: `displayTinymce() { document.getElementById('preloaderId').style.display = "none"; document.getElementById('tinymceContainerId').style.display = "block"; }` I hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't . I can't blindly use that coding. I need to initialize the preloader first, then recognize when tinymce has loaded completely and then hide preloader.

Comment: While searching this, I've found [link](http://demos.badsyntax.co/tinymce-preload.html).

Comment: @Jashwant I have accepted all the answers that gave me appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it on init of the editor (place this code in your tinymce init function)

```
...
theme: "advanced",   // example param
plugins = 'code',    // example param
setup: function (ed) {
    // gets executed when the editor is fully loaded
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
        // hide the loading image here
        // give css display: none to the preloader image
    });
},
cleanup: true,    // example param
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide editor before content not formatted:

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.onGetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
        jQuery('.mceEditor').hide();
    });
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
        jQuery('.mceEditor').show('slow');
    });
}
```